# Xamarin persist theme

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am only testing on an Android emulator.  I have installed the Theme Nuget packages.

In my App constructor I have:

```
        // Load the desired theme (default to Light)
        if (Current.Properties.TryGetValue("Theme", out object theme))
            Resources = theme as ResourceDictionary;
        else
            Resources = new LightThemeResources();
```

I then have a method in the App class:

```
    public async Task SwitchTheme()
    {
        // Switch the current theme from List to Dark to Light
        if (Resources?.GetType() == typeof(DarkThemeResources))
            Resources = new LightThemeResources();
        else
            Resources = new DarkThemeResources();

        // Persist the Theme
        Current.Properties.Add("Theme", Resources);
        await Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }
```

When I call the method the theme switches from light-dark-light etc.  But when I restart the App, it always defaults to Light.  As if the "await Current.SavePropertiesAsync();" did not work.

Can anyone suggest what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Forms `Properties` is intended for use with C# value types and objects that can be easily serialized - not complex objects like `Resources`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms)

> Values saved in the properties dictionary must be primitive types,
>   such as integers or strings. Attempting to save reference types, or
>   collections in particular, can fail silently.

All you really need to do is store a string value - either 'light' or 'dark' and then load the appropriate theme based on that.  You don't actually need to store the theme itself.

Comment: I was considering that next.  Let me try it.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that did it.  Marked as answer.